# Firebase blaze plan upgraded but not reflected in console

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I recently completed google credit card verification to upgrade my firebase account to Blaze plan. But still in firebase console my current plan is shown as "Spark (Free)".

Is this any verification delay from google? or something went wrong?

Comment: *firebaser here* If the console still shows you as on the Spark plan, the upgrade likely wasn't completed. Try upgrading again, and if that still doesn't work, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: I contacted google cloud support and they helped to solve the issue

Comment: Good to hear    And also thanks for posting the answer, as this may be helpful for others who hit upon the same problem.

Comment: How long does it take to upgrade though?

Comment: It was two years ago. It took only few hours ig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue happens when you have already completed the google cloud free trail period. You need to upgrade your billing account inorder to assign to a google cloud project (= firebase project).